# V number out of Tampa

Tags: meaning

I don't get the exact meaning of "V number out of Tampa" in the following context from Hemingway's To Have and Have Not.

> Freddy Wallace's boat, the Queen Conch, 34 feet long, with a V number out of Tampa, was painted white.

"V number out of Tampa" means that the boat is called V number out of Tampa? Tampa is a region? It is too difficult to understand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boat named *Queen Conch* had a  Vessel registration number from Tampa, Florida

*Out of Tampa* means that the boat was normally moored in Tampa, Florida

The name of the boat is additionally a play on the nickname of people from Key West called "Conchs"

the V-number is likely the **FL XXXX YY** here

[image]

and not the HIN which is
  * not mandatory until 1972,
  * too small to be seen from more than a few meters away
  * will identify the maker of the hull and not where the boat came from

[image: HIN]
<sub>(source: [georgiawildlife.com](http://www.georgiawildlife.com/sites/default/files/uploads/wildlife/boating/HIN%201.JPG))</sub>

Comment: So, the V number for the picture above, is 11, right? :)

Comment: No - fl 9361 nx like a number plate

Comment: yeah, 11 is too short to identify each boats. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'V number' is a mistake/slang for vehicle identification number (VIN); a boat has a Hull Identification Number (HIN)

[The first 2 numbers indicate the State](http://www.privilege42.com/hin.html). There was and is [no law](http://www.firstboat.com/boatnames.html) *that restrict(s) you from choosing a boat name that is already in use* and this likely is why a boat displayed the 'V number' in a well-used port **before** the implementation of the statute.

> The preferred location of the HIN is the **starboard outboard side of
>   the hull aft**. The HIN is **also located on the transom** of a boat. The
>   HIN is required by law to be located in 2 places of the boat, usualy
>   the hull aft and the transom. Since 1972 The HIN is a series of
>   alphanumeric characters which determine Manufacturer, Series, and Date
>   of Certification

Comment: I very much doubt that a HIN is large enough to be visible from more than a meter away.

Comment: I am suffering for so many mistakes and contraction in this book...  But I like this novel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: _The first three characters are a MIC (Manufacturer Identification Code)_ - does not tell you from where the boat hails, only what state the manufacturer came from.

Comment: 'To Have and Have Not' was written in 1937 and the confusion is in quoting post-publication references or statutes.  Private boats were registered with a 'V' number -as any insurable property- for the purposes of identification.

Comment: This explanation seems (though incorporating the new law) explains the history:  "M means motor and the V means vessel. On govt vessels like navy ships the letters tell you what govt or country the ship is owned by. On small private boats in the states the initials of the state will be present that it was registered in plus a number. EX: CA. 453387 This would mean California registration number 453387." https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070612195346AAB7RhL